# Column that starts with AST and ends in only number

Tags: mysql, regex

I suck at REGEX, but I need to pull all the records from a table column that stats with `AST`, and the rest only contains numbers after. I am assuming this can be done with just REGEX and not LIKE but I'm not sure.

For instance `AST000001`

and not `AST99XXH011`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'AST%' AND column REGEXP '[0-9]$'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`REGEXP/RLIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) on the whole column value (using start-of-string (`^`) and end-of-string (`$`) anchors to ensure you match the entire column):

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `column` REGEXP '^AST[0-9]+$'
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7jFAhsbGRWjkX33hjKLHHp/1)